# Combining Module pattern with Prototype

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

I am trying to encapsulate some methods by using module pattern. I am also trying to avoid new function definitions on new object creation by using a prototype. The problem is I have to implement a constructor and I couldn't figure how. My code:

```
 // constructor
function Anagram(original) {
  this.original = original.toLowerCase()
  this.sortedOriginal = this.sort(this.original)
}

// prototype as a module
Anagram.prototype = (function() {
  function isAnagram(word) {
    word = word.toLowerCase()
    return this.original != word && sameLetters(word)
  }
  function sameLetters(word) {
    return this.sortedOriginal === sort(word)
  }
  function sort(str) {
    return str.split('').sort().join('')
  }
  return {
    match: function(words) {
      return words.filter(isAnagram, this)
    }
  }
}())

module.exports = Anagram
```

Running

```
Anagram.new('ant').match(['tan', 'stand', 'at'])
```

Fails with

```
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'sort'
```

And I understand why, `sort` is not defined in the constructor. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a library called [`augment`](https://github.com/javascript/augment) which combines the module pattern with prototypal inheritance. For example you could implement your `Anagram` "class" as follows using `augment`:

```
var augment = require("augment");

var Anagram = module.exports = augment(Object, function () {
    this.constructor = function (original) {
        this.original = original.toLowerCase();
        this.sortedOriginal = sort(this.original);
    };

    function isAnagram(word) {
        word = word.toLowerCase();
        return this.original !== word && sameLetters.call(this, word);
    }

    function sameLetters(word) {
        return this.sortedOriginal === sort(word);
    }

    function sort(str) {
        return str.split("").sort().join("");
    }

    this.match = function(words) {
        return words.filter(isAnagram, this);
    };
});
```

Now you can use it as follows:

```
new Anagram("ant").match(["tan", "stand", "at"]);
```

See the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GbWXB/

---

**Edit:** If you wish you could use `deflcass` as a drop in replacement for `augment`:

```
function defclass(base, body) {
    var uber = base.prototype;
    var prototype = Object.create(uber);
    var constructor = (body.call(prototype, uber), prototype.constructor);
    constructor.prototype = prototype;
    return constructor;
}
```

See the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/sy4fz/

Comment: Thanks, intersting solution, but is there a way to solve my problem without external libraries?

Comment: Sure. You can use `defclass` as a drop in replacement for `augment`. See my updated answer.

Comment: I tried to understand defclass and I have to admit it's mindbending for me. Especially the line `var constructor = (body.call(prototype, uber), prototype.constructor);` could you explain it? And can you suggest some reading on the topic?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that sort is not a property of the prototype.  The prototype only has one property called match, to fix it - you need to put sort on the prototype of Anagram.  So where you return an object literal with the "match" function, that object also needs a "sort" function property.

```
return {
   match: function(words) {
      return words.filter(isAnagram, this)
   },

   sort: function(str) {
      return str.split('').sort().join('')
   }
}
```

Thus every Anagram inherits two functions from it's prototype and this.sort() is valid.

However there are a few other problems with your code.  The functions that you define which are not part of the returned object that becomes the prototype (e.g. sameLetters), are not going to be bound to the proper "this".  If you want them to get the correct value for this - they need to also go on the prototype, or you need to pass them a reference to this when you call them.

Comment: Your code wouldn't work as `sort` is called in `sameLetters`, not just in constructor.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to `this` problem. Is there a way to hide a function in closure and have it reference a proper `this` unless passed explicitly?

Comment: Not exactly is the short answer to that.  The value of this depends on the way the function is invoked, so if you want to have a "private" function which is not on the prototype then you need to pass 'this' to that function.  Otherwise `this` is inferred from the object you call the function on.  You could do something like : `privateUtilFunction.call(this, word)` from a function on the prototype, but you have to make sure that whenever you call `privateUtilFunction` you ensure 'this' is set.